# Homotopy category of Chain complex - isomoprhism = quasi isomoprhism?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, model-categories

Let $Ho(Ch_Z)$ be the localization of the category of nonnegatively graded complexes of abelian groups, $Ch_Z$, wrt the quasi-isomorphisms.

---

If two objects are isomorphic, in this localization, then are they quasi isomoprhic? I do not think this is true. But why in [page 43 of DS's notes](http://folk.uio.no/paularne/SUPh05/DS.pdf), we have two objects in $A,B \in Ho(Ch_Z)$ for which the author concludes 
$$H_iA \cong H_iB$$

---

I know this may be the case when $A,B$ are special objects. The problem is I cannot really tell if this is case in the notes.

Comment: Yes, it's true, pretty much by definition. Why don't you think it's true?

Comment: I could not really find the problem in the notes you link, but maybe I am not familiar enough with the situation to see it. Anyway, note that homology factors through the localization with respect to quasi-isomorphisms since these induce isomorphisms on homology groups. Thus homology becomes a functor $Ho(Ch_Z) \to Ab$ and so if two objects are isomorphic in $Ho(Ch_Z)$ they will have isomorphic homology. This does not imply the existence of a quasi-isomorphism between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : There could also be a zigzag sequence $A \to C$ and $B \to C$ of quasi-isomorphisms without the existence of a quasi-isomorphism $A \to C$. I guess it depends on what 'quasi-isomorphic' is supposed to mean.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch One says that two chain complexes are quasi isomorphic if there exists a zigzag of quasi isomorphisms, not necessarily a direct one... Otherwise you don't get an equivalence relation.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I agree this is the "correct" definition of the notion of quasi-isomorphism for homotopy theoretic purposes, but I've almost always seen "quasi-isomorphism" defined to be a map $X \to Y$ inducing isomorphisms on all homology groups.

Comment: I would commend zou go to the bounded case, not just negatively graded, and indeed, that is not too trivial to answer, in particular since you do not have at the moment necessarily a model structure, or another way of guaranteeing that your localization is actually a category (those zigzags may lead to morphisms not being sets).

Comment: @leibnewtz You are confusing "quasi isomorphism" (a noun that denotes a certain class of maps) and "quasi isomorphic" (an adjective that applies to chain complexes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking: no, as commented before, the zigzags make problems (assuming you already tamed them into defining sets of morphisms, which you can via classical construction and embedding your category in the category of bounded chain complexes), for example consider the following 2 complexes of abelian groups (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$-modules):
$$ 0\to 0\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \to 0 $$
and 
$$0\to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \to 0\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to 0 $$

then ther just can't be a quasi-imorphism going either way between those complexes (there are no nontrivial morphisms from $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to $mathbb{Z}$). However, both are quasi-isomorphic to 
$$0 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$.

Regarding your question in the proof:
as mentioned before in the comments, you none the less get a zigzag of quasiisomorphisms (in worsecase to a projective resoltion or a cofibrant fibrant replacement, depending on the setting you are working in), which then all induce isomorphisms of $H^*$, but those are now actual isomorphisms in the category of groups, hence you can actually invert them, and make the zigzag into a single iso.

Also, be aware that often people (especially when using model categories) restrict themselves to certain subcategories, for example $\mathcal{Ho}(\mathcal{C})$ usually is the subcategory of fibrant-cofibrant objects modulo homotopy.

Comment: I wonder if you might have a look at my recent question on definition of a cyclinder object.